# MS ODBC Alpine Support

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, alpine-linux

I want to add [PHP drivers for SQL server](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql) to my Alpine-based docker image. The extension requires MS ODBC driver package but [there's no Alpine support](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/300). AFAIK, ODBC is just a standard, does it mean that the extension should work with [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) (which exists in alpine repos). If not, is there a way to submit a request for Alpine support to MS ODBC team?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't speak for any of the projects involved; I think it would be very, very unlikely that Microsoft would support Alpine Linux.

Your best bet would be to use unixodbc, freetds, write a 'translator' (ie, have an Ubuntu docker image or even a service on the mssql server expose a web interface), or even just use a different linux (Microsoft seems to support Ubuntu quite well) for your docker images.

Comment: I agree...in the meanwhile, Alpine WSL landed in Microsoft Store: https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/p/alpine-wsl/9p804crf0395?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Answer (score 0):

I thought that's what the the [php5-mssql](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=*mssql*&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) packages were for, but from the sound of the post you linked, they may not be working. It wasn't clear to me why they would be there if that's the case. Perhaps the [PDO ODBC](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=*pdo_odbc*&branch=v3.6&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) drivers would be sufficient for what you need. (There's also php5-odbc and php7-odbc packages.) It couldn't hurt to use APK to add them to the Alpine base and see if they work for you. If at first, you don't succeed, `docker rmi` to remove the evidence.

Comment: php5-mssql is only for PHP 5.6 and the extension it's built on was [removed from php 7.0+](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php)

Comment: I was afraid of that. In that case, using the PDO or straight php 7 ODBC drivers might be a way forward.